# Get reference of facebook access token - Facebook SDK 4.X

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, facebook-ios-sdk, amazon-cognito

I have been using Facebook's login functionality to link to AWS Cognito system. To link them you require the `String` of Facebook's access token. Prior to version 4.0 I used

```
NSString *facebookToken = FBSession.activeSession.accessTokenData.accessToken;
```

Since the update this no longer works. I tried

```
NSString *facebookToken = FBSDKAccessTokenChangeNewKey;
```

But this also didn't work. Any suggestions? I can't find it in the reference guide or sample projects.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
FBSession.activeSession.accessTokenData.accessToken;
```

has changed to

```
[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken].tokenString
```

Answer (score 1):

The [facebook upgrade guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/upgrading-4.x) seems to show that FBSession.activeSession has been replaced with [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] as of 4.0. Does making that change fix your issues?

Comment: Hi @jeff. `[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]` doesn't produce a string value and I can't seem to find a child method of it to produce one.